# SVN: Delete existing repository and add a new one with same name

Tags: svn

I need to remove an existing svn repository and add a new repository with same name. The situation is, I had a repository named 'myproject' in my svn and for some reasons I was deleted that repository. Now I want to create the same again and I think svn doesn't allow that. Is there any possible solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Repository from FS-view is just directory, if you deleted it nobody prohibit you to create the dir with same name again